# Can't get all dataColumn values by ResultSet

Tags: java, json, jdbc, resultset

I have  table  named  testTable( in sql server  2014) and  i  have  one column  called holidays  inside it , in my  case  i   have two  values  inside this   column  for  example (2018-03-02 and   2018-04-02) and  i use  this method   for getting this  value  and then  puttinh it in json  Object here  is  my code:

```
public static JSONArray convertToJSON(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    while (resultSet.next()) {

        int total_rows = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < total_rows; i++) {


            jsonArray.put(obj.put(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i+1)
                    .toLowerCase(), resultSet.getObject(i+1)));

            }
    }
    System.out.println(jsonArray);
    return jsonArray;
}
```

but when i  run  this code    i  got only   last  data  written two  times  in my  array  it  will look like this :

```
[{"startDate":2018-03-02},{"startDate":2018-03-02}]
```

but  it should   look like this:

```
[{"startDate":2018-03-02},{"startDate":2018-03-03}]
```

I mean   it  writes  last  data  twice  but  when i try   to  print  it  in console i  got   right values?
what  should  i change to  get  all startDate  values  properly?

Comment: You're reusing your `JSONObject` instead of creating a new one for each iteration...

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel  thank  you  for   your  comment  if  i  make jsonObject  at a every  for  loop iteration and  also add  this  object  to  Json array(this  will  solve  my  problem?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the record by doing the following operation

```
jsonArray.put(obj.put(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i+1)
                            .toLowerCase(), resultSet.getObject(i+1)));
```

While putting the object your key is `startdate` which gets overwritten

```
obj.put(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i+1)
                                .toLowerCase(), resultSet.getObject(i+1))
```

Also, there is something wrong with your logic. The following code will give you column count and NOT the row count

```
int total_rows = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
```

You can use the following snippet to get the object:

```
public static JSONArray convertToJSON(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("startDate" , resultSet.getString('holidays'))
        jsonArray.put(obj);
    }
    return jsonArray;
}
```

Comment: Hi  @Yati Sawhney  thank  you  for  your  answer,How  should  i  get  rowCount   resultSet.rowCount()  gets  only current  raw  number,what  should  i    use  to  get  raw  number?

Comment: @TkhilaishviliSalome  I have edited the same. I am Assuming the value to be the string. Modify it if you want.